# Possible for Sublime Text 2 to save on loss of focus?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Textmate can save files when I switch focus to another application (that is, on blur).

Is it possible to set this up in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Open your "File Settings - User" settings file (Command+, on the Mac) and add the following line:

```
"save_on_focus_lost": true
```

In addition, you can open the "File Settings - Default" file (Sublime Text 2 menu > Preferences) to see all the default settings. Override settings in your User file, since this Default file may be changed by software updates.